# How to convert one row into multiple rows in SQL like this

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
Name    CPP  Java  Python Age

David    1    1     0     40

Mike     1    0     1     50
```

I want to generate a row for each non-zero CPP/Java/Python value with other non-zero values cleared:

```
Name    CPP  Java  Python Age

David    1    0     0     40

David    0    1     0     40

Mike     1    0     0     50

Mike     0    0     1     50
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way would be to do a union, eg,

```
SELECT name, cpp, 0 as java, 0 as python, age
FROM {table}
WHERE cpp = 1
UNION ALL 
SELECT name, 0 as cpp, java, 0 as python, age
FROM {table}
WHERE java = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT name, 0 as cpp, 0 as java, python, age
FROM {table}
WHERE python = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

this should do the magic:

```
SELECT name, cpp, 0,0, Age FROM table WHERE cpp = 1 UNION ALL
SELECT name, 0, Java,0, Age FROM table WHERE Java = 1 UNION ALL
SELECT name, 0, 0,Python, Age FROM table WHERE Python = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want to do is something like this:

```
SELECT t.Name,t.CPP,t.Java,t.Python,t.Age FROM(
  SELECT Name, CPP, 0 AS Java, 0 AS Python, Age Where CPP = 1
  UNION  
  SELECT Name, 0 AS CPP, Java, 0 AS Python, Age Where Java = 1
  UNION  
  SELECT Name, 0 AS CPP, 0 AS Java, Python, Age Where Python = 1 ) t
ORDER BY t.Name ASC;
```

Hope this helps.